# Latin prefix to describe the wiping out of robots

Tags: neologism

Does the "gen" from "genocide" come from "genus" as in "race"?  If so, what Latin prefix should one use to describe the wiping out of robots? I can't say "codacide" can I? Automatacide?

Comment: It seems that it comes from [Greek _genos_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=genocide) and the 'correct' construction (with both roots in Latin) would have been _genticide_. **Robotum** is attested (see. e.g. _Pons Wörterbuch des neuen Lateins_.) Hence _roboticide_ (but probably works better for one robot.)

Comment: Since _genocide_ does not specify the race (but suggests humanity,) it seems logical to use a more general term that you can later specify, like [_classicide_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classicide) of robots. (Here, _class_ is applied to classes of beings rather than social classes.)

Comment: "robocide" perhaps, like English "robopsychology"?

Comment: Rafael is probably right that a compound with *-i-* rather than *-o-* would be better as that type is more standard, but "mixed" compounds do have a long history (e.g. *[protosedeo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dprotosedeo)*).

Comment: What's wrong with "robot genocide"?

Comment: Historically there have been anti-technology movements named after people: *luddism* (after Ned Lud) or after methods of attack: *sabotage* (after the *sabot*, the clogs said to have been thrown into machines to break them). If the story you're writing features this wiping-out as a single movement/event (rather than you wanting to talk about robot-wipings-out generally) then it may be more realistic to come up with a one-time name rather than a *-cide* word.

Comment: Does it have to be Latin?  I'd say _cybercide_ myself.

Comment: Cybercide sounds a bit like "killing someone via the Internet".

Answer (score 8):

My vote is for *automatocide* for the following reasons:

(1) *automatos / αυτοματος* (sg), *automata / αυτοματα* (pl) is attested in ancient literature as referring to self-acting, autonomous, mechanical beings.  Some examples include:

- The self-opening gates of Olympus (*αυτομαται πυλαι*) in Homer, Iliad,
  5.749
- The self-moving tripods Hephaestus made, referred to as *οι αυτοματοι* / the autonomous ones, in Homer, Iliad, 18.376
- A reference to “miraculous automatic puppets” (*τα αυτοματα των θαυματων*) in
  Aristotle, Generation of Animals, 734b11

I think the nominalised adjective *automata* is broad enough to encompass a variety of mechanical, autonomous beings (in response to Rafael’s comment about "classicide").

(2) as an example of its use in a compound form, we have *automatopoiika / αυτοματοποιικα* from [Philo of Byzantium's](http://www.encyclopedia.com/science/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/philo-byzantium) (fl. ca. 250 BC) engineering manual on how to build *automata*.

(3) I know you asked for a Latin prefix but as Rafael established, the *gen-* of genocide has a Greek root so using *automato-* seems legitimate.  Also, I’m not aware of any Roman writings on robots whereas the Greeks wrote about robot-like beings quite frequently, hence the ready-made term *automata*.

EDIT (4) *automatum* does appear in Latin works, although very rarely.  In Petronius, it does seem to refer to an automaton or at least a clockwork toy of some sort:

- *ne per parietem automatum aliquod exiret* / lest some automaton leap out of the wall (*Satyricon*, 54)

In Suetonius, however, it seems to be more of an ordinary mechanical device, not intended to look or act like a human:

- *si automatum ... parum cessisset* / if a device ... had worked insufficiently (*Lives of the Caesars: Claudius*, 5.34)

[Admittedly weaker] alternatives from classical literature could include (note: these are my own neologisms, based on the literature):

*Mechanicide*: from the story in Polybius’ *Histories* of the robot tax-collector’s wife who crushed and pierced recalcitrant tax payers to death.  She is referred to as a machine / *μηχανη* (13.7).  Of course, this could so easily be misunderstood as killing of mechanics, so perhaps not that useful!  On the plus side, however, this is the same "machine" of *deus ex machina* (a Latin calque of the Greek *απο μηκανης θεος*), which post-Matrix/Ex Machina/various sci-fi and anime movies/video games, and philosopher [Gilbert Ryle's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_machine) “ghost in the machine”, is used as a reference to AI.

*Chalkicide* (pronounced kalkicide): from the story of Talos, the robot who guarded Crete, in Apollonius’ *Argonautica* (4.1638-1686).  Talos is referred to as a bronze man / *χαλκειος* (4.1638).  Hence my offering of *chalkicide*.  This is clearly flawed as it looks like death to chalk!

*Talicide*: in honour of poor Talos / *Ταλως* who was tragically killed in the line of duty by the witch Medea.

If I were to read *roboticide* in a book, I would know exactly what it meant and, to that end, it works.  However, *pace Pons Wörterbuch des neuen Lateins*, I don’t think *robotum* is real Latin but rather a Latinisation of the Czech word [*robotnik*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=robot) / a slave, itself from *robota* / slave workforce, from the verb *robtotiti* / to work.  This is from Old Slavic and doesn’t seem to have any roots in either Greek or Latin.  English adopted the word robot from the Czech author Karel Capek’s play *R.U.R. Rossum's Universal Robots*.

Comment: Automatocide also has gravitas. Chalkicide would be too obscure without readers looking it up.